# Is there a API endpoint to share elements (files, items, sites, ...) with other users in Sharepoint online and on-premise via REST API (in C#)?

Tags: xamarin, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-rest-api

I am required to create a share feature (like the one in Sharepoint or OneDrive) for documents, items and folders, for Sharepoint online and on-premise, in a Xamarin app.

What I have:

- Sharepoint REST API.
- Xamarin app connected to a Sharepoint online and on-premise server.
- Sharepoint content is available in Xamarin app and user can select the option Share item which I have to implement.

What I need:

- The logic to implement to be able to create the shareable link and actually share it like the Sharepoint website online does it (check screen shot).

[image: Sharepoint Online share feature performed in a folder]

Answer (score 3):

@Mohamed Aloui,

You could have a try the below endpoint to create a sharing link:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle(‘Documents’)/Items(1)/sharelink
```

or

```
/_api/web/GetFileByUrl(@v)/ListItemAllFields/ShareLink?@v='/sites/testsite/Mylib/test.txt'
```

You can get an example through F12 tool:

[image]

[image]

Below is a tutorial blog and a similar thread, you may take a reference:

- [How to create a shared link with an expiration date for the item of OneDrive For Business via Rest API?](http://devchat.live/en/2018/07/03/how-to-create-a-shared-link-with-an-expiration-date-for-the-item-of-onedrive-for-business-via-rest-api/)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/84801/calling-the-sharelink-sharepoint-rest-api-endpoint.html

BR